# How can I get conditional formatting to work across a row? (Lottery Spreadsheet)

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

Image here of what I'm trying to do, for a lottery spreadsheet:

[image: Numbers played: D to J. Winning numbers: K to P; row 5 has a matching number in Numbers played and winning numbers]

If a number in the "Numbers Played" row shows up in the "Winning Numbers" section on the right, in the same row, I need it to highlight that number.

I thought I had it working, but in the 4th row, in the "Winning Numbers" section there is a 19, and there is also a 19 in the "Numbers Played" section, but it's not highlighting.

How can I get the "Numbers Played" row to highlight a number, if that number is in the same row on the right, in the "Winning Numbers" section?

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). To make it easier to answer your question, please show a [table](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/editing-help#tables) of sample data rather than screenshots.

Answer (score 1):

Create a [conditional formatting](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413) custom formula rule for the range `D3:I` with this formula:

`=countif($K3:$P3, D3)`